# Bubble sort prevents my program from executing

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a bubble sort that will shift the position of several parallel arrays based on the string "desc", in ascending order. When I run the program, I just get a blank screen and the program never finishes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
const int maxp = 50;

void swap(string& a, string& b)
{
    string temp;
    temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
//These swapem functions are the functions used to move the array 
//values when the sort function is called
void swap(int& a, int& b)
{
    int temp;
    temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

void swap(char& a, char& b)
{
    char temp;
    temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

void swap(double& a, double& b)
{
    double temp;
    temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

void sort(int id[], string desc[], int numsold[], double price[], 
double dolars[], int nump)
{
    int i, j;
    for (j = 0; j < nump - 1; j++)
        for (i = 0; i = nump - 1; i++) //I'm sorting a group of parallel arrays by the 
            if (desc[i] > desc[i+1])//string "desc", and the others are being moved based off of that
            {
                swapem(desc[i], desc[i + 1]);
                swapem(id[i], id[i + 1]);
                swapem(numsold[i], numsold[i + 1]);
                swapem(price[i], price[i + 1]);
                swapem(dolars[i], dolars[i + 1]);
            }
}
int main()
{
    int id[maxp], numsold[maxp], nump;
    double price[maxp], dolars[maxp];
    string desc[maxp];
    ifstream inf;
    ofstream outf;
    inf.open("storesales.dat");
    outf.open("storesales.ot");
    outf.setf(ios::fixed);
    outf.precision(2);
    initem(desc, id, numsold, nump, price, dolars);
    readem(id,numsold,nump,price,desc);
    printem(id, desc, numsold,nump, price, outf);
    getsales(numsold, price, dolars,nump);
    sortem(id, desc, numsold, price, dolars, nump);
    printem(desc, id, numsold, nump, price, dolars, outf);
    system("pause");
}
```

I know that these functions are the problem because I retested them and commented the calls out, the program finished. The problem is, I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: please don't post code with `void main`. It won't compile with many compilers, because it's non-standard. `int main` is **shorter** and standard.

Comment: just a silly question why are you want `j` to loop `nump-1` times? you should stop when no swap in the nested loop occurs... which mean stop when sorting is done. Otherwise your sort will always take the worst case runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nasted loop in `sortem()`:

```
for (i = 0; i = nump - 1; i++)
```

should be condition instead of assignment i.e:

```
for (i = 0; i < nump - 1; i++)
```

---

Second parameter of `for` loop is expected `condition`. Assignment `i = nump` always return `true` thereby *infinite* loop. As a result, your blank screen.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. Sorry for the simple question, I can't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 1):

the error is in the 2nd loop

for best performance you can have the inner loop as follows:

for (i = j; i < nump - 1; i++)

Answer (score 1):

As this is already answered just few silly suggestions:

**Why are you want `j` to loop `nump-1` times?**

You should stop when no swap in the nested loop occurs... which mean stop when sorting is done. Otherwise your sort will always take the worst case runtime.

```
for (j=1;j;) // loop while j is set
 for (j=0,i=0;i<nump-1;i++) // reset j
  if (desc[i] > desc[i+1]) // if swap needed
   {
   swapem(desc[i], desc[i + 1]); // swap elements
   swapem(id[i], id[i + 1]);
   swapem(numsold[i], numsold[i + 1]);
   swapem(price[i], price[i + 1]);
   swapem(dolars[i], dolars[i + 1]);
   j=1; // and set j so this loops until array is ordered
   }
```

Also you are using parallel arrays which have its merits but I think in your case use of `struct` or `class` would be far better simplifying the code (especially the swap) a bit having single array with all the info inside.

Comment: The reason that I used the parallel arrays and the way that wrote the sort was because that's the way my professor told us to do the program. If I were to try to do it another way I might have lost points, so I just tried to make it work with that format.